Assigning manage-users role to confidential client with Keycloak
I've been trying to assign some management roles to the service account of a confidential client that I've set up, however it seems like I've probably set up my call wrong, since I'm getting a 404 error:
{"error":"User not found","error_description":"For more on this error consult the server log at the debug level."}
The admin endpoint I'm using is POST {host}/admin/realms/{realm}/users/{userId}/role-mappings/clients/{clientId}, where realm is a valid, active realm I created, userId is the id of the confidential client's service account, and clientId is the id of the confidential client.
The request body looks like [{ id: {roleId}, name: {roleName}]. The role I'm trying to assign is manage-users, defined in the auto-generated realm-management client.
I've fetched the realm-management client id by calling GET host/admin/realms/{realm}/clients, and looking for the entry with the specified name.
I got the service account id by calling  GET {host}/admin/realms/{realm}/clients/{clientId}/service-account-user using the client id I got from the previous step.
And finally, I got the role id for manage-users using GET {host}/admin/realms/{realm}/clients/{clientId}/roles using the same client id.
Am I calling the wrong endpoint? Or have I supplied the wrong ids somewhere along the way?

Turns out you actually need to pass in the realm-management client id to the initial role mapping call. That was it.
